# Significance of ? in generics

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, generics

Went through a code snipped online

```
public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities(Integer role) {
        List<GrantedAuthority> authList = getGrantedAuthorities(getRoles(role));
        return authList;
    }
```

A. Can any please tell me what does `?` signify?

B. `<? extends GrantedAuthority>` which class is extending GrantedAuthority?

C. In generics we provide the class type in <> to ensure type safety, why would anyone want to  provide A extends B within <>?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a wildcard which means any type that is extending Object(which also includes object).

So you can say that `<?>` is a shorthand for `<? extends Object>`

Check [Oracle docs for Type Arguments and Wildcards](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.5.1)

From [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/wildcards.html):

> In generic code, the question mark (?), called the wildcard,
>   represents an unknown type. The wildcard can be used in a variety of
>   situations: as the type of a parameter, field, or local variable;
>   sometimes as a return type (though it is better programming practice
>   to be more specific). The wildcard is never used as a type argument
>   for a generic method invocation, a generic class instance creation, or
>   a supertype.